# Android: Get number of groups in ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, expandablelistview

is there a way to get the number of groups in an ExpandableListView? Or do I have to "remember" how many group items I have added?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get the group count through the `ExpandableListView`'s adapter:

```
ExpandableListView v;
[...]
final int groupCount = v.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount();
```